# How to detect history.pushstate in WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

I developed hybrid iOS application with Swift
and want to detect history.pushstate() in WKWebView.
I did override WKWebView's methods, but I couldn't detect anything.

Is there a way or trick to detect history.pushstate()

Comment: What do you mean by override?

Comment: @gyre It means that I used "func webView(blah blah blah)"

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly a workaround, but if you are allowed to edit properties of built-in objects (like in most browsers) you can wrap both functions and use an intercepting handler to track when they are called:

```js
function track (fn, handler) {
  return function interceptor () {
    handler.apply(this, arguments)
    return fn.apply(this, arguments)
  }
}

history.pushState = track(history.pushState, function (state, title, url) {
  // do something with `state, `title`, and `url`
  console.log('pushState called with:', { state: state, title: title, url: url })
})


history.replaceState = track(history.replaceState, function (state, title, url) {
  // do something with `state, `title`, and `url`
  console.log('replaceState called with:', { state: state, title: title, url: url })
})

history.pushState(null, 'Title 1', '/example-page')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can observe `WKWebView.url` through [key-value observing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/using-key-value-observing-in-swift)

```swift
var urlObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?

...
let webView = WKWebView(...)
urlObservation = webView.observe(\.url, changeHandler: { webView, change in
    print("url changed")
})
```

It seems that [Firefox for iOS](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios/wiki/WKWebView-navigation-and-security-considerations) is also using this way.